# Doubly LL insertion at end stuck on loop

Tags: java, data-structures

I can't seem to figure out why inserting a node at the end of a doubly linked list is getting stuck in a loop. Either its stuck in a loop or null pointer. Also I'd like to know if public Node is better or public void when dealing with linked lists or any data structures.

```
public Node insertEnd(int data) {
    Node newNode = new Node(data);
    newNode.next = null;
    if (head == null) {
        head = newNode;
        return newNode;
    }

    Node last = head;
    while(last!=null) {
        last = last.next;
        last.next = newNode;
    }
    newNode.previous = last;
    return newNode;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, its because of this part of the logic

```
    Node last = head;
    while(last!=null) {
        last = last.next;
        last.next = newNode; //// This shouldn't happen.
    }
```

Once the linked list is already created, you're trying to go to the last element. However, during that traversal you've also changed the next pointer to which the node was pointing to.

Try to change your logic to:

```
public Node insertEnd(int data) {
    Node newNode = new Node(data);
    newNode.next = null;
    if (head == null) {
        head = newNode;
        return newNode;
    }

    Node last = head;
    while(last.next != null) {
        last = last.next;
    }
    last.next = newNode;
    newNode.previous = last;
    return newNode;
}
```

Comment: This was what i did in the beginning and it will not work, it gives me a null pointer exeption.

Answer (score 1):

In your `while` loop:

```
while(last!=null) {
    last = last.next;
    last.next = newNode;
}
```

The second line sets `last.next` to `newNode` so on the next iteration, `last` will be set to `newNode`, who's `next` field is null. You only want to set `last.next` to `newNode` once `last.next == null` (When you have reached the end of the list):

```
while(last.next != null) {
   last = last.next;
}
last.next = newNode;
```

Comment: Yes, i have tried that and set the newNode.previous to last, but it gives me a null pointer execption.

Comment: @madil26 I cannot reproduce this. Could you post a [MCVE] please?

Answer (score 1):

As for the second part of the question, it depends on the way a client/caller of this API would expect the output to be.

Are you writing this API to be used in another program you're writing? In that case, think about if it will be useful for you to get the newly created Node as a return value of this API, or if it is acceptable to leave it as void.

For reference, the Java implementation of the API has `void` as the return type. (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#addLast(E))

Comment: I'm just using to node it makes it easier for me to grasp the idea of linked list. But from my undrestanding it shouldnt matter if its void or Node as long as it works, but i know its not convention when it comes to APIs

Comment: Your understanding is correct, in this case it does not matter as long as it works. 

Also, since your initial question is unresolved, could you update the question with the stack trace of the NPE? Does it throw an NPE when you insert for the first time or the subsequent times?

Comment: public Node insertEnd(int data) {
     Node newNode = new Node(data);
     newNode.next = null;
     if (head == null) {
         head = newNode;
         return newNode;
     }

     Node last = head;
     while(last.next != null) {
         last = last.next;
     }
     last.next = newNode;
     newNode.previous = last;
     return newNode;
 }

Answer (score 1):

To answer 1st part , you need to make following changes in your code -

```
 Node last = head;
    while(last.next!=null) { // be careful- it should be last.next!=null instead of last!=null , as it will give null pointer exception.
        last = last.next;    
    }
    last.next = newNode;
    newNode.previous = last;
    return newNode;
```

as the statement "last.next = newNode;" in while loop was setting last to newNode in the first iteration itself.

for 2nd part of your question, it depends on the requirement of calling function.